# How to set the ES_HEAP_SIZE environment variable on OS X

Tags: elasticsearch, environment-variables

Using OS X 10.10.4, Elasticsearch 1.6.0 from Homebrew so server runs as Launch Agent on login:
`/usr/local/bin/elasticsearch --config=/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

Question: How to set the environment variable ES_HEAP_SIZE to use 2gigabytes of RAM? What should I write and in which file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found an answer:

open the LaunchAgent (or Daemon) plist. In my case:

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch.plist
```

Add:

```
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
      <key>ES_HEAP_SIZE</key>
      <string>2g</string>
    </dict>
```

Comment: That file gets overwritten if brew services is used (i.e. brew services restart elasticsearch will nuke that file). The values need to be added to the plist that's in the cellar version. At the time of my writing this, that location is "/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/2.3.5" for me.

Comment: I guess things have changed since the above comment. Setting the key in this file worked for me and my homebrew install (ES 2.4.0).